hashicorp consul doesn't deregister critical/failed nodes
We are using hashicorp consul v1.4.4 as a service discovery in aws ec2, other spring boot applications running on separate ec2's registering itself with the discovery service and with each application there is consul agent running on each ec2. We facing issue with consul not deregistering nodes which are stale/failed. We used property
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-critical-timeout=1m
in application.properties file
it worked when tested locally with consul agent running on localhost:8500 and spring boot application running on local as well But on ec2's it is not working
